# How do I use "mysql source" command with a mysql variable?

Tags: mysql, variables

I need to execute from mysql shell an SQL file based on a condition like
mysql> source @var
where @var contains the filename

Answer (score 4):

This is not possible. `source` is a command that is recognized and executed locally by the MySQL client program. Variables exist on the server, so the client has no idea what `@variable` means.