# How to set path as user-defined variable properly in Mysql script?

Tags: mysql, windows

I am new in Mysql so excuse me for missing some relevant points during the explanation.
Well, I would like to create some scripts.sql and then just call them by another main script to setup a database. Example:

- script1.sql
- script2.sql
- script3.sql

Inside **script_main.sql** I would like to do the following code:

```
SELECT @scripts_path := 'C:\where\my\scripts\are';

SOURCE @scripts_path + '\script1.sql';
SOURCE @scripts_path + '\script2.sql';
SOURCE @scripts_path + '\script2.sql';
```

However, seems like I am declaring the scripts_path wrongly because it is returning:

```
C:wheremyscriptsare
```

Without slashes. I am wondering if there is some specif command to handle paths variables properly in mysql. I know I can use environment variables, but if there is no option I have to go with it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I use "mysql source" command with a mysql variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1638654/how-do-i-use-mysql-source-command-with-a-mysql-variable)

Comment: "Impossible" is a hard word in programming, isn't? Well, I think I will keep searching.

Comment: No it is the reality especially the part where is says server and client are different, when you understand that you understand why it can't work.